# Free place in div after scale in css

Tags: html, css, transform, scale, space

Good morning,
I have div with absolute width (500px) and auto height. I scaled an image in this div but after the scale, the div has height like before the scale.

html:

```
<div id="result">
  <div class="scale">
     <img src="https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/10/21/tuv_1-down.png">  
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#result {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background: green;
}

#result .scale {
    transform:scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform:scale(0.7);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/wpo6vdw2/)

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do? -- What's your expected output?

Comment: I would like delete the green space. The height of the box should match the picture

Comment: but you want to keep the green space to the side of the image?

Comment: No, the div should be big as picture after scale

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea. Until someone smarter comes around, I would scale the image manually in paint and embed that.

Comment: I can't edit it manually. I want pictures to be of good quality to copy to Word...